# PHP can't upload image and can't see $image value. all other work, it is about ajax, without refresh form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

HTML Form without refresh insert in database, i didn't copy full code, other input elements work, only $image dont insert in database also did't upload in directory. without ajax function everything work, but form have reload, i want without reload, if anyone can help me i tell you Thank you.

```
 html
 <form id="formid" method="post" action="phppath/sucms.php" 
  onsubmit="return fsocietyApp()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="img" class="f-col s12 m6 l6">
   <label for="uploadphoto">Upload picture</label>
   <input type="file" name="uploadphoto" id="uploadphoto">  
   <span id="fsoc" style="float:right;"></span>
  </div>
  </form>



javascript
functuin fsocietyApp(){
 if(document.getElementById("uploadphoto").files.length != 0 && ex != 
 "gif" && ex != "png" && ex != "bmp" && ex != "jpeg" && ex != "jpg") 
  {
    error.innerHTML = "<img style='position:relative;bottom:12px' 
  src='img/red.png' alt='error'>";
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
  data: $('#formid').serialize(),
  success: function(response){
   $('#success').html(response);
  }
 });
 var form = document.getElementById('formid').reset();
 error.innerHTML = "";
 return false; 
  }

 php
 $image = $_FILES["uploadphoto"]["name"];
 if($role == 'Admin' || $role == 'Author'){
    if(!empty($fname)){
        $q = "INSERT INTO `fusr` (`uid`, `udate`, `urole`, `uimg`, 
     `ufname`, `ulname`, `usrname`, `uemail`, `upsw`, `uviews`, 
      `udetails`) VALUES (NULL, '$date', '$role', '$image', '$fname', 
      '$lname', '$uname', '$email', '$password', '0', '$details')";
        if(mysqli_query($c, $q)){
            echo "hi";
        }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Please include the full PHP file/code, you are making several references to variable which have not yet been defined within it, so either that's the issue or you aren't showing us more code.

Comment: ok i will change 1 min

Comment: Also, by the way: Don't ever validate the file in your Javascript! I mean, it's okay to do in order to give the user a better experience, but if you're not validating server side, then I can just easily disable JS and upload a php shell, and then I have full access to your website because you didn't make sure to check the file type.

Comment: yes i know, i have add in my code <noscript> and in the noscript i have PHP validation form if anyone try to Disable javascript.

Comment: That's not a solution either. I could enable Javascript, but then open up my console log and overwrite those variables which are doing the validation. **YOU NEED TO VALIDATE SERVER-SIDE**.

Comment: you mean i filter it in PHP too yes?

Comment: Yes, in PHP you should be checking to verify that it's actually an image file. There are a few ways to do this, and some are terrible and don't actually work very well as they are easy to bypass.

Comment: yes, i have it, but if javascript is off after open new window, like this:
<noscript>
        <?php if(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) != "disable.php"){ ?>
            <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=disable.php">
        <?php } ?>
    </noscript>

Comment: Not entirely sure if that matters. So long as you are checking in PHP, as the above code can easily be bypassed by running JS initially but then turning it off once the page and contents have loaded. Or just sending a direct POST request with a php file and no validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chang from serialize() to new FormData() check below:

```
 var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
  data: formData ,
  success: function(response){
   $('#success').html(response);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Good solution. Just remember only to use this to improve the UI, not for actual functionality or validation as it is **client side**.

Comment: Are you here? @Devraj verma ?

Comment: something happening,  var formData = new FormData($('#formid'));
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
          data: formData ,
          success: function(response){
           $('#success').html(response);
          }
         }); when i use this code after and submit, open sucms.php page :(

Answer (score -2):

From you code correct the definition of the function fsocietyApp

```js
javascript
**function** fsocietyApp(){
 if(document.getElementById("uploadphoto").files.length != 0 && ex != 
 "gif" && ex != "png" && ex != "bmp" && ex != "jpeg" && ex != "jpg") 
  {
    error.innerHTML = "<img style='position:relative;bottom:12px' 
  src='img/red.png' alt='error'>";
    return false;
  }
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'phppath/sucms.php',
  data: $('#formid').serialize(),
  success: function(response){
   $('#success').html(response);
  }
 });
 var form = document.getElementById('formid').reset();
 error.innerHTML = "";
 return false; 
  }
```